# Фильтрация массива в js по первому символу

Tags: javascript

Изучаю понемногу js, учусь работать с массивами. Взял задание на сортировку массива и застопорился. Уже третий день голову ломаю. Код на входе получает массив с словами БЕЗ знаков препинания, слова просто разделены пробелом. Нужно найти подходящие слова в массиве по первому символу и вывести их. Мой код не хочет отбирать больше одного слова.
Буду очень признателен. :)

```
const arrTweets = [
  'Попробывал твитнуть',
  'Я уже совсем #обтвитовался',
  "Не #могу ничего #твинтнуть",
]

const lol = arrTweets.flatMap(sentence => sentence.split(' '))
let tweets = function (tweet) {
  var result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < tweet.length) {
    i++;
    let tweets = tweet[i];
    if (tweets[0] == "#") {
      result.push(tweet[i]);
      return result;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const words = arrTweets.flatMap(sentence => sentence.split(' '));
const result = words.filter(word => word.startsWith('#')); // ищем слова, которые начинаются с #
```